# Swipe to new stage then swipe back to previous stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to create a cake baking application, with a recipe on a separate stage to the main kitchen. i want the user to be able to swipe from the kitchen to the recipe at any point during the app, swiping to the recipe is easy enough as its never going to change so its just:

```
stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, onSwipe2);
function onSwipe2(e: TransformGestureEvent): void {             
    gotoAndStop(1, 'Recipe');           
}
```

But when trying to go back to the main stage which changes throughout the the program im finding a little trickier to figure out. can anyone help i've tried :

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

stage.addEventListener (TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, fl_SwipeHandler);

function fl_SwipeHandler(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
{
    prevScene();    
}
```

But nothing seems to happen

Comment: Do not use stages, ever. It is an archaic thing and a bad approach. You should always use Movieclips or Sprites for this purpose.

Comment: I think you all (OP and @Fygo) are confusing `scenes` and the `stage`. There's only one stage in a typical Flash application.

Comment: @frankhermes You are right, of course. I was talking about scenes, not stage. Thx to point it out!

Comment: I am new to fash sorry for the mistake, but is it possible to do it using scenes ????